# Any sequence in metric space has lim supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Does any sequence in any metric space have a limit supremum and a limit infimum?

If the sequence is growing, it would be $\infty$ if unbounded or a finite number if bounded.

If the sequence is decreasing, then it would be -$\infty$ or some finite number if bounded.

If the sequence oscillating, it should still have $+-\infty$ as an upper and lower bound. I guess it could also have $\infty^n$, but I am not sure about that.

If the sequence is random, but we know all of the elements in the sequence, shouldn't it still have bounds?

If it is not true that all sequences have lim supremum/infimum, then can someone provide an example or explanation please?

Comment: Asking this about "any metric space" makes no sense. What do "decreasing" or "oscillating"  mean for a set of points in the plane?

Comment: I'm asking about an arbitrary metric space. Why would it make no sense? Either there is an example of a metric space with out a limit supremum defined, or there isn't?

Comment: To ask about "growing" or "lim sup" the underlying space must have a linear order. Most metric spaces don't. The plane is an example where "lim sup" is not defined. so you can't ask whether or not a sequence has one.

Comment: Not following. What is an example of a sequence of numbers in a plane that does not have a limit supremum, if you can consider infinity as a limit supremum?

The plane does not have a linear order? I don't get that.

Comment: There is no "infinity" in the plane for a sequence of points to have as a lim sup. Perhaps you can learn more from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_metric_spaces

Comment: I think you mean that in an unordered plane, we don't know which is greater, [1,2] or [2,1]. 
But really, isn't [1,2] = [2,1], and [3,1] > [1,2] or [2,1], and the limit supremum should be $[\infty,\infty]$

Comment: You are wandering down a path that makes no sense, at least to me. I've tried to explain why. Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: If you think that [1,2]=[2,1] then you probably don't think of  [1,2] and [2,1] themselves, but about their distances to [0,0]. If you do so, then you should indicate it, since someone else might prefer to think of distances to a different point, say distances of [1,2] and [2,1] to [4,3], in which case [1,2] is bigger than [2,1]. You could easily define bounded and unbounded sequences in a metric space since the choice of a point to measure distances from won't matter in this case. But the sequence 1/n is decreasing if you measure distance from 0, but increasing if you measure distance from 1.